# Array to string conversion PHP SQL

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to print_r my code array :

```
$arr =  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 )
```

so, how i can get this value to insert to database?
because when i submit always error Array to string conversion

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cmdSubmitAspek'])) 
{
$nilaiBobot = $_POST['nilaiBobot']; 
$arr = $_POST['arr']; 

foreach($_POST['nilaiBobot'] as $key => $value ){

 $nilaiBobotTenp = $nilaiBobot[$key];
 $arr = $arr[$key];


$queryInsAspek = "insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, arr, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT)
              VALUES  ".$idDivisi.", ".$idDepartment.", '".$arr."','".$nilaiBobotTenp."',".$userID.", getdate()";
$resultInsAspek = sqlsrv_query($conn, $queryInsAspek);           
}
```

}

Comment: You will have to include the code which does the insert for us to help fully.

Comment: im just edit my question, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I expect the issue is that when you do:

`$arr = $arr[$key];`

you are completely overwriting the $arr variable, instead you need to use a temp variable for the current loop:

`$tempArr = $arr[$key];`

and reference that in your INSERT query instead.

Also, you should be using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)